# How to create 'multi depth' select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have an array of objects and I'm wondering how I can format it into a select box, using hyphens to represent each level deeper. Here's my object -

```
let elements = {
  0: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Parent folder',
    parent_id: null
  },
  1: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Another parent folder',
    parent_id: null
  },
  2: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Child folder 1',
    parent_id: 1
  },
  3: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Child folder 2',
    parent_id: 1
  },
  4: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Child of a child',
    parent_id: 4,
  },
}
```

I would like `elements` to then be re-formatted like below -

```
let elements = {
  0: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Parent folder',
    parent_id: null,
    depth: 0
  },
  1: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Child folder 1',
    parent_id: 1,
    depth: 1
  },
  2: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Child folder 2',
    parent_id: 1,
    depth: 1
  },
  3: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Child of a child',
    parent_id: 4,
    depth: 2
  },
  4: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Another parent folder',
    parent_id: null,
    depth: 0
  },
}
```

This way I could loop through the object and generate a select in the following structure based on the depth variable -

```
Parent folder
- Child folder 1
- Child folder 2
-- Child of a child
Another parent folder
```

Currently I am looping my object through a process and getting a multi level object, so maybe I just need to work out how to convert this back into a single depth array of objects?

```
if(elements.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        let obj = Object.assign({}, elements[i]);

        let depth = 0;
        obj.items = [];

        map[obj.id] = obj;

        let parent = obj.parent_id || '-';
        if (!map[parent]) {
            map[parent] = { items: [] }
        }
        map[parent].items.push(obj);
    }

    console.log(map);
    return map['-'].items;
}
```

I feel like there is a relatively simple answer to this but I'm struggling! Look forward to your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ADyson good point - I've added where I'm currently at to my question :)

Comment: If you would use an array instead of an object, you could sort the array on parent_id, so that all parent nodes are at the front. Then if you loop over that array, you can create all the elements without having to check for the parents existance.

Comment: @Shilly thanks for the response - but then how would I work out how deep each element is, surely I'd need to check the parents? Sorry if I'm being stupid - JavaScript isn't exactly my thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a tree first, to reflect the relationship and then build a flat array which later became an object.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach(function ({ id, name, parent_id }) {
        Object.assign(o[id] = o[id] || {}, { id, name, parent_id });
        o[parent_id] = o[parent_id] || {};
        o[parent_id].children = o[parent_id].children || [];
        o[parent_id].children.push(o[id]);
    });
    return o.null.children;
}

function getFlat(array = [], level = 0) {
    return array.reduce((r, { id, name, parent_id, children }) =>
        r.concat({ id, name, parent_id, level }, getFlat(children, level + 1)), []);
}

var elements = { 0: { id: 1, name: 'Parent folder', parent_id: null }, 1: { id: 2, name: 'Another parent folder', parent_id: null }, 2: { id: 3, name: 'Child folder 1', parent_id: 1 }, 3: { id: 4, name: 'Child folder 2', parent_id: 1 }, 4: { id: 5, name: 'Child of a child', parent_id: 4 } },
    tree = getTree(Object.assign([], elements)),
    flat = getFlat(tree);

console.log(flat.map(({ name, level }) => '-'.repeat(level) + name).join('\n'));
console.log(Object.assign({}, flat));
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I was just building a depth variable into your code when you submitted it ;) I'll get this implemented and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Great, this worked towards my eventual solution so thanks a lot! I actually kept the original tree generation from my question, but used your flattening to add a depth parameter. Thanks for the help!